# Sequence and Limit

Tags: calculus, analysis

If $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=1$, $0\leq a_n\leq 1 \; \forall n\in N,$ then what about the $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_n)^n$. Is this limit exists? If yes then what is the value of this limit?

Comment: If $a_n$ approaches $1$ (its limit) *exponentially quickly*, then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)^n=1$ as well.

Answer (score 4):

It depends.

For instance, if $a_n=1$ then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=1$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_n)^n=1$

On the other hand, $b_n=1+\frac{1}n$ verifies $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n=1$, but $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(b_n)^n=e$

Comment: Thanks. If $0\leq a_n\leq 1$ for all $n\in N,$ then is there any definite result?

Comment: No : take $\frac{1}{b_n}$

Comment: The better example would have been $b_n=1-\frac1n$. We know that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(b_n)^n=\frac1e$, and it's also between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Actually, my $b_n$ is equal to your $\frac1{b_{n-1}}$, so my suggestion is equivalent to yours (except off by one).

Answer (score 1):

And $\displaystyle \lim_{n->\infty} n^{\frac{1}{n}}=1 $ but $\displaystyle \lim_{n->\infty} (n^{\frac{1}{n}})^n=\infty $

It can also simply not have any limit :

$a_{2n}=n^{\frac{1}{n}}$

$a_{2n+1}=1+\frac{1}{n}$